# Is it ok to use http dropbox file links instead of https?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Using dropbox '/media' API call I've obtained a direct https file link. Something like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/asdfasdfasdfasd/file.ext

Then I've changed it from 'https' to 'http' and successfully downloaded the file. Obviously enough, the modified link looked like this:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/asdfasdfasdfasd/file.ext

My question is wether it's ok to use http links or not? Is it some sort of dropbox bug or a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. I get a 400 error when I try to do the same thing.

Even if HTTP is working for you, I'd advise against using it. Someone eavesdropping on your traffic could learn the link to the file, and it's also possible for someone to impersonate `dropboxusercontent.com` and send you the wrong data.

It's probably best to stick with HTTPS.